# mongodump - range query on timestamp filed raising FailedToParser Error

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

The following is the structure of the documents:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fccd39c9d8597a034d183b1"),
  "image" : "23ef514f8201320c2d7253e4bf28edf6",
  "owner" : "1b8c335c902ac4ab128ee8ed773bee04",
  "pageviews" : 57,
  "source" : "b1b3849b472edada1b922c786df5b46f",
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2012-06-04T00:00:00Z")
}
```

I am doing the following `mongodump` query to dump all documents with `timestamp` greater than November 1, 2013:

```
mongodump -d dbname -c coll_name -q "{source: "7e04f65e47ed3ddfeb21716a247e3fa6", timestamp: {\$gte: new Date(2013, 10, 1)}}"
```

And it shows:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '}' or ',': offset:13
```

Even though the same query object (except for the backslash used for escaping `$gte`) works fine in `mongo` shell. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. the version of MongoDB is 2.4.6

Comment: Here's the related MongoDB bug [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12390]

Comment: bug resolved May 15 2015: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-725

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a problem with your nested quotes:

```
mongodump -d dbname -c coll_name -q "{source: "7e04f65e47ed3ddfeb21716a247e3fa6", timestamp: {\$gte: new Date(2013, 10, 1)}}"
# ----------------------------------^---------^
```

I'd use single quotes on the outside:

```
mongodump -d dbname -c coll_name -q '{source: "7e04f65e47ed3ddfeb21716a247e3fa6", timestamp: {$gte: new Date(2013, 10, 1)}}'
```

That also lets you avoid escaping the `$gte` too. And if it doesn't like the `new Date` then you could use:

```
{$gte: new Date(1383264000000)}
```

---

For posterity, it seems that the `-q` parser doesn't like the three argument form of the `Date` constructor nor does it like the `ISODate` function that MongoDB usually uses for dates and timestamps. I get confusing assertions failures like:

```
Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: timestamp
```

when I try either of those. This is pretty puzzling to me but sometimes it is better to just quietly walk away once a workable solution is found.

Comment: I got this when I tried your query:

`assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: First character in field must be [A-Za-z$_]: offset:78`

Comment: It doesn't like the `new Date(2013, 10, 1)` either? Does it like `ISODate('2013-11-01')` better?

Comment: Got it working by trying this:


`{source: "7e04f65e47ed3ddfeb21716a247e3fa6", timestamp: {$gte: new Date(1383264000000)}}` Could you edit your answer so I can accept? Thanks.

Comment: Updated. Does it take `{$gte: ISODate("2013-11-01")}`?

Comment: Nope: `assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:62`

Comment: Wow, that makes no sense at all. I'm actually getting assertion failures from deep inside the JSON parser when I use the three argument Date constructor or ISODate. Wow.

Comment: This is a bug in the parser for mongoexport, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12390

Answer (score 0):

in my case problem was with different versions of mongodb.

Problem

> 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset

occurred when I tried restore on 2.4 mongodb version backup from 3.0 version.